# No significant interaction in OLS, but significant in pairwise comparison

Tags: regression, least-squares, interaction, nonparametric, paired-data

I have two independent categorical variables — (i) `A: {1, 2, 3}`, (ii) `B: {0, 1}` — with a continuous outcome variable `Y` (*not normally distributed*). My hypothesis states that, as you increase `A`, the difference between `Y at B=0` and `Y at B=1` will increase (i.e. line slope). See the following diagram:

[image]

To me, it seems like a clear case of variables interacting, and so I ran OLS with `A*B` interaction; however, the OLS showed that no significant interaction occured. This was strange because the graphs showed significant difference between slopes of lines `A=0` and `A=1,2` (although admittedly `A=1,2` were almost identical).

To double-check I ran a non-parametric pairwise comparison (Dunn's Post-Hoc test) between the 6 combinations of these categories, which showed that the difference between `(A=1, B=1)` and `(A=1, B=0)` is not significant, while the difference between `(A=2, B=1)` and `(A=2, B=0)` is significant (same for `A=3`).

My questions are:

- Given this, in my work, could I say anything about the variable `A` interacting with `B`, even though OLS interaction term is not significant, but pairwise comparison indicates that `Y` is affected differently given `A=0` vs. `A=1,2`?
- Could pairwise comparison be used to show progression: the higher the `A`, the more `Y` is affected given `B`?

Thank you!

**---------------------------------------------------**

**EDIT**

(1) Sample size based on  G*Power calculation with small effect (0.02), power of 0.8, and alpha 0.05 should be 550 participants, however, due to high attrition rate, **my final sample consists of 344 participants**.

(2) Here is the **actual graph** produced after OLS:

[image]

[image]

(3) Here is the **output of the OLS**:

[image]

(4) As can be seen the interaction terms are not significant. However, it can also be seen that lines `A=1` vs. `A=2,3` are **divergent**. This is further seen in non-parametric pairwise comparison tests (Dunn's test), which was performed after confirming using Kruskal-Wallis test:

[image]

The red box indicates that the ends of line `A=1` are not significantly different, while ends of lines `A=2,3` are (green boxes).

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Did you have a sufficient sample size to detect the effect size that you are interested in ? If not then perhaps the study is simply under powered.  You may get better answers if you include the full model formulae, the full output/summary from those models and also the details of the full tests that you did.

Comment: Hi @RobertLong ! Thanks for your suggestion. I've included extra information about my case in the edited question above. Would appreciate if you have any thoughts on this. Cheers!

Comment: Your information indicates this is an underpowered study with suggestive, but not significant, results.  The search for significance has caused you to conduct many tests (at least 30 with this dataset) and correcting for those multiple comparisons (as well as adjusting for the fact most of the tests were suggested by analysis of the data themselves) further reduces the indications of an interaction.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @whuber. Indeed, I see your point regarding the study being underpowered. What I am still wondering, however, is whether the results from pairwise comparison can be used to suggest interaction between A and B variables, when it comes to A=1 being significantly different from A=2,3. Is it perhaps that OLS considers the interactions over the whole range of values of A, thus not being a good indicator of the effect between different groups within A? Thanks again.

Comment: If you had originally intended to test such specific interactions your results would be stronger.  However, because these differences emerged as the result of an (evidently) intensive search for differences, their apparent strength can be deceptive.  You definitely should not trust the small p-values.